# What is the use of 2>?

Tags: io-redirection

What is the use of:

> ```
> 2>
> ```

in an SSH command?

Answer (score 0):

That is not related to `ssh`, it's a shell function to redirect the standard error messages. Read about [shell redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)

Answer (score 0):

This redirects standard error output to somewhere. Non-related to the SSH.

Post exact command if needing more info.

Example of redirection:

```
/usr/bin/veracrypt > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Parsing:

1. VeraCrypt is an encryption program, that floods terminal with all kinds of messages
2. `>` redirects output
3. `/dev/null` is the black hole in Linux
4. `2>&1` combines standard error output to standard output, so all the possible printed messages will go to the black hole
5. `&` runs the program into background

Answer (score 0):

These are Single-line redirection commands (affect only the line they are on). File descriptors `0` represents standard input, `1` represents standard output and `2` represents standard error.

e.g.

`1>filename` - Redirect stdout to file "filename"

`1>>filename` - Redirect and append stdout to file "filename"

`2>filename` - Redirect stderr to file "filename"

`2>>filename` - Redirect and append stderr to file "filename"

There are many more.